# place floating tables and figures in order of appearance

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

In my document I number tables and figures with the same counter, using the answer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865036/using-a-single-count-for-figures-and-tables-in-latex/7771554#7771554.

I'd like them to appear in numerical order. That usually happens, but in one case I see Figure 1.2 after Table 1.3 - probably because the Table is smaller and happens to fit on the current page.

I could fix this by *calling* this Table a Figure without torturing the text too much, but a `LaTeX` solution would be automatic.

If no one answers soon I can put together an MWE by playing with Figure, Table and page lengths.

The question and answer at [Order of float types on float pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113496/order-of-float-types-on-float-pages) seems to deal with the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

LaTeX keeps all floats of the same *type* in order, so you need (at least)

```
\makeatletter
\let\ftype@table\ftype@figure
\makeatother
```

so figures and tables are the same type (1)

Comment: Can this be done for selected figures only? I want specifically one figure and one table to be in the order of their definitions.

Comment: @Somebody In that case it's probably easier to use `\begin{figure}` for the special table so it doesn't pass any figures and use `capt-of` or `caption` package `\captionof{table}{......}` so you make a table caption not a figure one

Comment: Good, your script must be anywhere in the preamble?

Comment: David's reply also helped me for a kind of hijacked use or misuse: it helped me to place one table right below a figure, in the correct order of appearance in the code. Using one single float (either figure or table) environment was not an option in my case as I had to keep the specific formatting of the captions and so (IEEE journal). Not that a short story but I have no time for now to open a new thread on it.