# Should tables go before or after figures?

Tags: floats, positioning

I am preparing a document with a lot of figures and also some tables (both, figures and tables are usually very wide, about textwidth, and not very high). Sometimes it is inevitable to put two float objects on the top of the same page. Now I have two two questions:

1. Are there any layout rules if the table or the figure should come first? Personally, I find it more appealing to have the table below the figure because it looks more text-like.
2. How could such a general rule be implemented?

   - One idea: if LaTeX sees that two float objects go on the same page, it should check whether one is a table and put it below the other, if that one is a figure.
   - Another idea would be to have to distinct lists of float objects that are to be printed and prioritize one over the other.

I hope, question 1 is not too opinion-based and question 2 is not too difficult. Note that this is not essential, just a thing that I was wondering about. So it's more a conceptual question. Though I would not mind having a working solution in the end (but at the moment I don't have the time to dig deep into TeX).

Comment: How big are the figures? If they are small, you could put them in a `wrapfig` environment and then float the tables. Also if there are lots of tables and figures, are they all discussed in equal depth? If not, some could perhaps be put in an appendix.  There is also the `placeins` package, which gives you the command `\FloatBarrier` (the use of which you can probably guess).

Comment: I know about the `\FloatBarrier` but this would involve manual tweaking, the easier way would be just to interchange figue and table, if I am not satisfied with a given result. Still, I would like to interchange them only when needed (i.e. when they would appear on the same page).

Both, figures and tables are rather wide (almost or equal to \textwidth) but not really high, so wrapfig would not help much, also I don't like having a text around a picture - I rather relign two narrow pictures in one figure environment.

Comment: Well, you can see that it's not just a matter of taste regarding #1: no one else knows what kind of figures and pictures are involved --- which makes it difficult to answer. For #2, have you looked at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127744/8528) (particularly the comments)?